# Prime Number Test always returns true

Tags: java, primes

So I just started some java and I'm trying to get the user to enter a number and test whether it is prime or not. This is the loop I have for the program.

```
do{
        for(testNumber = 2; testNumber < numb; testNumber++){
            if(numb % testNumber == 0){
                test = false;
            }else{ 
                test = true;
            }
        }

        if(test = true){
            System.out.println("The number is prime.");
        }else{
            System.out.println("The number is not prime.");
        }

        System.out.println("Enter a number. Enter 0 to exit.");
        numb = number.nextInt();

    }while(numb != 0);
```

Every number that is entered becomes out to be true! To me the logic seems to be correct.

Comment: This question has been asked so many times... just look for a prime number generator and learn from it.

Comment: Some suggestions: If you want to make it faster, set up your loop so you're not testing even numbers and you're only testing until numb/2 rounded up.

Answer (score 3):

```
if(test = true){
```

should be

```
if(test == true){
```

The first one being an "[assignment](http://www.particle.kth.se/~lindsey/JavaCourse/Book/Part1/Java/Chapter02/operators.html)" operator and the second one being a logical (equality test) operator. Read more on the [official documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/opsummary.html).

---

#### Note

I am not commenting on other parts of your code as a learning exercise for you. Your code can be optimized and improved! You're on the right track. Keep it up!

Answer (score 2):

First, your are using the assignment operator `=` to compare `test` to `true`, which results in `test` always being `true`.  It's already a `boolean`, just use it without the extraneous comparison:

```
if(test){
```

Second, you are overwriting the value of `test` in each `for` loop iteration.  Initialize it to `true`, and only set it to `false` if you find a factor.

```
test = true;
for(testNumber = 2; testNumber < numb; testNumber++){
    if(numb % testNumber == 0){
        test = false;
    }
}
```

Additionally, you don't need to test `testNumber`s past the square root of the number `numb`.

```
int limit = (int) Math.sqrt(numb);
for(testNumber = 2; testNumber <= limit; testNumber++){
```

Comment: Fastest gun in the west much? :)

Comment: You probably want `(int) Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(numb))`. Never know when you'll have an infinitesimal underflow and truncate a `.999999999999`.

Comment: Thanks, removing the  "= true" worked.

Answer (score 0):

You should break if you found it and if condition == true

```
do{
        for(testNumber = 2; testNumber < numb; testNumber++){
            if(numb % testNumber == 0){
                test = false;
                break;
            }else{ 
                test = true;
            }
        }

        if(test == true){
            System.out.println("The number is prime.");
        }else{
            System.out.println("The number is not prime.");
        }

        System.out.println("Enter a number. Enter 0 to exit.");
        numb = number.nextInt();

    }while(numb != 0);
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work? I enter 4 but the program still prints it out as prime.

Comment: you tried it after my edit of the condition? the break will just make your program faster

Comment: Yes, I added break; after test = false; but it still showed 4 as being prime.

Comment: if(test == true) not if(test = true) this is the edit

Comment: Oh, sorry, didn't see that. Yep it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems. First, think about your loop logic: You're actively setting the `test` variable on every pass through the loop. Since the loop ends at `numb - 1`, it's nearly always going to set `test` to `true` on the last pass. Instead, set `test` to `true` before the loop and only set it to `false` if you find a factor: That will leave it `false` as soon as you detect it's not prime. (Putting that loop inside a separate method so you can `return` immediately would be even better.)

```
isPrime = true;
for(int factor = 2; factor < numb; factor++) { // see below for advice on condition
    if(numb % factor == 0)
        isPrime = false;
}
```

Second, you're *setting* `test` in your `if` statement. You must use `==` to check for equality, and in Java, it's more idiomatic to just use `if(test)`.

As a matter of style, a variable named `test` is not very descriptive. I suggest the `isPrime` name I used above.

Finally, you only need to check up to the square root of `testNumber`, but don't use a floating-point operation and then truncate the result, or you might miss an exact square-root factor.

Comment: FYI, I don't think truncating the result of `Math.sqrt` is a problem for `int`, because `int` is 32 bits and `double` has a 52-bit mantissa.  I just ran a test and I don't think there is any `int` for which it could fail.  `long` could be a problem.